# c# subtract a number from every element in an array?

Tags: arrays, numbers, subtraction

I am using an int array with elements 4,5,6
I am trying to subtract 1 from every element of my array so the correct array's elements are 3,4,5

Comment: Okay, what have you tried so far, and what was/were your result/s? I mean, what is the problem with `array[index] = array[index] - 1;`?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
for(int i=0;i<arrayName.count;i++)
{
    arrayName[i]=arrayName[i]-1;
}
```

Welcome to SO. This is a pretty easy problem, you should learn a bit more about arrays before asking such questions in the future though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
arrayName = arrayName.Select(x=> (x-1)).ToArray();
```

To use LINQ, you have to use the namespace `System.Linq`.